# Is it possible to hide sap.m.input "description" property value

Tags: sapui5

I'm using the description field to hold an value that I don't want to be displayed, is it possible to set this property to visible:false or set to width to 0?

```
new sap.m.Input("idAltDistInput"+refDocID+sequenceID, {value:"{AltDistrictDesc}",
description: { path : 'AltDistrictID' }
:
```

visible : false doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why do you want to hold the value? What is the purpose of that? Give us more details in your question, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: So, i'm probably just being lazy and using the description & value properties to bind to two different columns in the oData model. It as more of convenience, both values are set when a row of a dialog popup box is selected. But i just wanted the value to be visible

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by adding StyleClass.

```
sap.m.Input("id",{
   //Properties
}).addStyleClass("InputDescripTionHidden");
```

Add following css

```
.InputDescripTionHidden>span{
   display:none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comment above suggests that you want to store some hidden value, for later use.

Rather than "hijack" (in the nicest sense of the word) another property, you should consider using Custom Data, which is designed for this sort of thing. Here's an example.

```js
new sap.m.List({
    mode: "SingleSelectMaster",
    items: {
      path: "/records",
      template: new sap.m.InputListItem({
        label: "District",
        content: new sap.m.Input({
          value: "{AltDistrictDesc}",
          customData: [new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
            key: "DistrictID",
            value: "{AltDistrictID}"
          })]
        })
      })
    },
    select: function(oEvent) {
      var id = oEvent.getParameter("listItem")
        .getContent()[0] // the Input control
        .getCustomData()[0] // the only Custom Data
        .getValue();
      alert("Selected District ID : " + id);
    }
  })
  .setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    records: [{
      AltDistrictID: "D1",
      AltDistrictDesc: "District 1"
    }, {
      AltDistrictID: "D2",
      AltDistrictDesc: "District 2"
    }]
  }))
  .placeAt("content");
```

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>
<div class="sapUiBody" id="content"></div>
```

(Note that for simplicity, I'm just grabbing the first content and the first custom data within that content in the select listener. You will want to do this slightly more precisely in real code.)

Comment: Thanks Dj, you are right and I was "hijacking" the field for binding to a model element. Thanks for the example above, i re-jigged my code to use the custom data and it worked fine. I used the setKey & setValue as below after the dialog popup value is selected.    customData = sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.altDistrict).getCustomData()[0];
   customData.setKey(this.altDistrict);
   customData.setValue(oSelectedItem.getTitle());